# how to change a tuple into dictionary tree in python

Tags: python, dictionary

there is a tuple like this:

```
t = (
  (1, -1, 'python'),
  (2, -1, 'ruby'),
  (3, -1, 'php'),
  (4, -1, 'lisp'),
  (5,  1, 'flask'),
  (6,  1, 'django'),
  (7,  1, 'webpy'),
  (8,  2, 'rails'),
  (9,  3, 'zend'),
  (10, 6, 'dblog')
)
```

I want to change it to a list, and every list item is a dictionary. this dictionary has a key son is another dictionary . how to change the tuple t , i hope to be a list-dictionary tree like this:

```
l = [
{
    'id': 1,
    'fid': -1,
    'title': 'python',
    'son': [
        {
            'id': 5,
            'fid': 1,
            'title': 'flask',
        },
        {
            'id': 6,
            'fid': 1,
            'title': 'django',
            'son': [
                {
                    'id': 10,
                    'fid': 6,
                    'title': 'dblog',
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            'id': 7,
            'fid': 1,
            'title': 'webpy',
        },
    ]
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'fid': -1,
    'title': 'ruby',
    'son': [
        {
            'id': 8,
            'fid': 2,
            'title': 'rails',
        },
    ]
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'fid': -1,
    'title': 'php',
    'son': [
        {
            'id': 9,
            'fid': 3,
            'title': 'zend',
        },
    ]
},
{
    'id': 4,
    'fid': -1,
    'title': 'lisp',
}
```

]

thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried to write any code? If you have, post your attempt and the output it generates.

Comment: How do you know who is whose parent?

Comment: @bereal: presumably the second value in the tuple

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah true, "fid" must stand for "father id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = []
entries = {}

for id, fid, title in t:
    entries[id] = entry = {'id': id, 'fid': fid, 'title': title}
    if fid == -1:
        l.append(entry)
    else:
        parent = entries[fid]
        parent.setdefault('son', []).append(entry)
```

Here `entries` keeps track of all entries that have been created so far, so that you can add 'sons' to them directly without having to search the tree.

This assumes that your list `t` is properly sorted by `id` and that sons only ever are children of lower ids.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> t = (
...   (1, -1, 'python'),
...   (2, -1, 'ruby'),
...   (3, -1, 'php'),
...   (4, -1, 'lisp'),
...   (5,  1, 'flask'),
...   (6,  1, 'django'),
...   (7,  1, 'webpy'),
...   (8,  2, 'rails'),
...   (9,  3, 'zend'),
...   (10, 6, 'dblog')
... )
>>> l = []
>>> entries = {}
>>> for id, fid, title in t:
...     entries[id] = entry = {'id': id, 'fid': fid, 'title': title}
...     if fid == -1:
...         l.append(entry)
...     else:
...         parent = entries[fid]
...         parent.setdefault('son', []).append(entry)
... 
>>> pprint(l)
[{'fid': -1,
  'id': 1,
  'son': [{'fid': 1, 'id': 5, 'title': 'flask'},
          {'fid': 1,
           'id': 6,
           'son': [{'fid': 6, 'id': 10, 'title': 'dblog'}],
           'title': 'django'},
          {'fid': 1, 'id': 7, 'title': 'webpy'}],
  'title': 'python'},
 {'fid': -1,
  'id': 2,
  'son': [{'fid': 2, 'id': 8, 'title': 'rails'}],
  'title': 'ruby'},
 {'fid': -1,
  'id': 3,
  'son': [{'fid': 3, 'id': 9, 'title': 'zend'}],
  'title': 'php'},
 {'fid': -1, 'id': 4, 'title': 'lisp'}]
```

If the 'fid-comes-after-id' assumption doesn't hold up, you need to add a queue of child ids to be processed still:

```
l = []
entries = {}
queue = {}

for id, fid, title in t:
    entries[id] = entry = {'id': id, 'fid': fid, 'title': title}
    if id in queue:
        entry['sons'] = queue[id]
        del queue[id]
    if fid == -1:
        l.append(entry)
    elif fid in entries:
        parent = entries[fid]
        parent.setdefault('son', []).append(entry)
    else:
        queue.setdefault(fid, []).append(entry)

if queue:
    raise ValueError('No entries found for fid(s) {}'.format(queue.keys()))
```

Now the order of entries in `t` can be entirely random:

```
>>> import random
>>> t = list(t)
>>> random.shuffle(t)
>>> l = []
>>> entries = {}
>>> queue = {}
>>> for id, fid, title in t:
...     entries[id] = entry = {'id': id, 'fid': fid, 'title': title}
...     if id in queue:
...         entry['sons'] = queue[id]
...         del queue[id]
...     if fid == -1:
...         l.append(entry)
...     elif fid in entries:
...         parent = entries[fid]
...         parent.setdefault('son', []).append(entry)
...     else:
...         queue.setdefault(fid, []).append(entry)
... 
>>> if queue:
...     raise ValueError('No entries found for fid(s) {}'.format(queue.keys()))
... 
>>> pprint(l)
[{'fid': -1,
  'id': 1,
  'son': [{'fid': 1, 'id': 7, 'title': 'webpy'},
          {'fid': 1, 'id': 5, 'title': 'flask'},
          {'fid': 1,
           'id': 6,
           'sons': [{'fid': 6, 'id': 10, 'title': 'dblog'}],
           'title': 'django'}],
  'title': 'python'},
 {'fid': -1,
  'id': 2,
  'son': [{'fid': 2, 'id': 8, 'title': 'rails'}],
  'title': 'ruby'},
 {'fid': -1,
  'id': 3,
  'son': [{'fid': 3, 'id': 9, 'title': 'zend'}],
  'title': 'php'},
 {'fid': -1, 'id': 4, 'title': 'lisp'}]
```

The `fid` can be any `id`, as long as that id is named *somewhere* in sequence `t` or is `-1` for root entries.

Comment: That's assuming that the initial list is properly ordered.

Comment: @freakish: yup, which the posted list in the question is.

Comment: That's just an example. Otherwise no algorithm would be needed (just return a predefined dictionary). IMHO you are assuming too much about the data.

Comment: @freakish: added a queue for fatherless entries.

Comment: Well, you still assume that fid < id holds for every entry. Sorry for being picky. :) That's a very nice trick with a queue, though.

Comment: @freakish: No, that doesn't. `fid` can refer to any of the ids as long as `fid != id`.

Comment: +1: Yep, you're right. I've misunderstood the algorithm. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate dictionary that maps ID to local id-fid-title-son dictionary. Stitch the local dictionaries together after finding the fid in the separate dictionary. If the fid of the local dictionary is -1, add it to the list. This works because the local dictionary is the same object regardless of what contains it.

Answer (score 0):

If the initial list is properly ordered then have a look at Martijn Pieters solution. However if you can't guarantee the order then one of the solution is to loop twice over the initial list:

```
children = {}
objs = []
l = []
for id, parent, title in t:
    obj = {
        "id": id,
        "fid": parent,
        "title": title
    }
    objs.append(obj)

    if parent == -1:  # keep only roots
        l.append(obj)

    if parent not in children:  # append to children
        children[parent] = []
    children[parent].append(obj)

for obj in objs:
    if obj["id"] in children:
        obj["son"] = children[obj["id"]]
```